# does my toilet have a venting issue?

Tags: toilet, vent, drain-waste-vent

My toilet is making a slight gurgling noise at the end of the flush. Here is a video of the flush:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/yIcFN14zdgDAAFu43

The toilet is vented via a 2" vent that meets the toilet about 6" after its flange fittings. All the vents and drains are at the correct pitch or greater:
[image]

I am wondering if I should have put the vent coming in the back of a sani-y instead of meeting up with the toilet post 45 elbow. Would this have been a better solution:

[image]

Or is there a better solution out there?

Comment: A little gurgle is part of the physics this breaks the vacuum created when the water is draining and leaves the amount in the bowl equal to the height of the u bend or trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is correct. Try to keep the vent opening (the 2" branch of wye) within 2' of the stool flange. It appears the wye is rolled up slightly, which is good.  The toilet gurgle could be due to design of toilet.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I guess I will just let it roll. The Y is rolled up. I wanted it to be rolled up to a 45 and thats what it was in the dry fit, but then once I glued it it is more like a 25 degree angle. Somehow that always seems to happen...